# QFileSystemWatcher does not signal changes in system file

Tags: linux, qt

I tried to use QFileSystemWatcher to signal changes in sys fs files  (Ubuntu 16.04) such as `/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate`
Under some circumstances this is possible:
https://www.embeddeduse.com/2018/09/18/monitoring-sys-files-qfilesystemwatcher/

The following example signals changes in ordinary files such as `/home/user/file.txt` but gets nothing from system ones, changed externally (e.g. `sudo ifconfig eth0 up/down`)
Launching from superuser changes nothing.

```
void QWatcherObserver::onFileChanged(const QString &path)
{
    qDebug() << path;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QFileSystemWatcher *watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(&a);
    QWatcherObserver *observer = new QWatcherObserver(&a);
    a.connect(watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(const QString&)), observer, SLOT(onFileChanged(const QString&)));
    watcher->addPath("/sys/class/net/eth0/operstate");
    return a.exec();
}
```

Is there a way to  use QFileSystemWatcher with system files? What are the requirements for the watched files and OS?

Comment: Have you tried simply watching with the `inotify` command?  If that can't see the changes, then it's not a Qt problem - the Ethernet driver is not notifying the filesystem layer.  In general, files on `sysfs` and `procfs` are not all watchable.

Comment: inotifywait gives the same behavior. But QFileSystemWatcher has several mechanisms of polling and inotify is only one of them. Is it possible to force QFileSystemWatcher to specific mechanism (such as poll)? Or it depends upon OS configuration only?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to change the driver (I haven't read it, but it likely just fetches the current state when it's read, so it has no means to notify the filesystem in any way - no changes to last-modified or anything like that that can be used).  The only alternative I know is to create a thread that polls reading the content every few seconds and emit its own signal when there's a change.